# setting spring configuration for multiple profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have more than one profile in my application configuration file, `application.yml`, like the following example:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-super-app
database:
  secret: "default secret"
this:
  that: "default value..."

---

spring:
  profiles: staging


---

spring:
  profiles: qa
database:
  secret: "foo bar"

---

spring:
  profiles: playground
database:
  secret: "foo bar"

---

spring:
  profiles: production
database:
  secret: "foo bar"
```

As it is obvious, I redundantly set the `database.secret`configuration for `qa`, `playground` and `production` profiles, except `staging`. Is there a way to set it once for these three profiles, something grouping the profiles or inheriting from a base profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the profiles in a comma separated list (`qa,playground,production`), like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-super-app
common-secret: "foo bar"
database:
  secret: "default secret"
this:
  that: "default value..."

---

spring:
  profiles: staging


---

spring:
  profiles: qa

---

spring:
  profiles: playground

---

spring:
  profiles: production

---

spring:
  profiles: qa,playground,production
database:
    secret: "foo bar"
```

Alternately you can set a "shared variable", something like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-super-app
common-secret: "foo bar"
database:
  secret: "default secret"
this:
  that: "default value..."

---

spring:
  profiles: staging


---

spring:
  profiles: qa
database:
  secret: ${common-secret}

---

spring:
  profiles: playground
database:
  secret: ${common-secret}

---

spring:
  profiles: production
database:
    secret: ${common-secret}
```

Comment: yes, but it has a side effect: the `common-secret` will also be visible to all profiles including staging. which does not sound right to me.

Comment: Your original question didn't specify any constraints on the scope of the solution. What I have suggested does work. I will add an alternate solution to my original answer that will satisfy your additional requirement.

Comment: @Mualik In response to your 1st comment: "`common-secret`  will also be visible to all profiles including staging": although it is "visible" to the staging profile (and all profiles), it in fact has no effect on the staging profile, since the staging profile does not use the variable ${common-secret}. It only has an effect on the profiles that include `database.secret: ${common-secret}`, like qa, playground and production.